# AttributeError when attempting to add colorbar with heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a heatmap to illustrate the correlation between attributes. I get an error when I attempt to add the colorbar to the figure. Here's the code and image:

```
def housing_heatmap(data=housing_copy):
    columns = data.select_dtypes(exclude='object').columns
    corr_matrix = data.corr()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
    ax.matshow(corr_matrix, cmap='jet')

    ax.set_xticks(range(len(columns)))
    ax.set_yticks(range(len(columns)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(columns)
    ax.set_yticklabels(columns)
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='left', rotation_mode='anchor')
    plt.colorbar(corr_matrix)

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    return None


housing_heatmap()
```

This code gives an error while producing the image. Here's the image:

[image]

And here's the error that is caused by the line:

```
plt.colorbar(corr_matrix)
```

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'
```

Is there any way that I could add the colorbar for the heatmap without producing this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the image to `plt.colorbar`, not the matrix itself:

```py
def housing_heatmap(data= housing_copy):
    columns = data.select_dtypes(exclude='object').columns
    corr_matrix = data.corr()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
    mat_plot = ax.matshow(corr_matrix, cmap='jet')

    ax.set_xticks(range(len(columns)))
    ax.set_yticks(range(len(columns)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(columns)
    ax.set_yticklabels(columns)
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='left', rotation_mode='anchor')
    plt.colorbar(mat_plot)

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

housing_heatmap()
```

[image: colorbar fixed]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's wondering, I took @RobinFrcd's answer into account and also specified the `fraction` and `pad` keyword arguments in [`matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html#matplotlib-pyplot-colorbar).

```
def housing_heatmap(data):
    columns = data.select_dtypes(exclude='object').columns
    corr_matrix = data.corr()

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
    mat = ax.matshow(corr_matrix, cmap='jet')

    ax.set_xticks(range(len(columns)))
    ax.set_yticks(range(len(columns)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(columns)
    ax.set_yticklabels(columns)
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha='left', rotation_mode='anchor')
    plt.colorbar(mat, fraction=0.045, pad=0.05)

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

produces the following image:

[image]

You can change the values of `fraction` and `pad` to get the colorbar size you want.

Hope this helps anyone out there.

Comment: I typically use shrink and aspect to get the colorbar the correct size.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea as well, I didn't know about that. Thanks! :)